# Why am I always asked to unlock my login keyring at startup?

Tags: linux, login, xfce

I'm using the xfce window manager and reboot and shutdown seem to work normally.

However, whenever I log back in, I always see the following:

[image]

Why do I always see this message? I would expect that my screen would be blank or at least be locked up, but nothing like that happens. What's the point of entering my password again?

Answer (score 5):

Your keyring is separate from your login credentials. In Ubuntu (which I'm guessing you're using), there has always been confusion on this issue. If you [make your log in password the same as your key ring password](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1541936), it should fix the issue.

Comment: My log in password and key ring password is the same I think, because I just enter in my login password to unlock the key ring.

Comment: Do you have automatic log in turned on? (Where it logs you in to desktop, but doesn't ask for a password).

Answer (score 3):

This could be a PAM problem.

Authentication providers/packages need to change the PAM configuration files to plug themselves into the authentication process. However, some of them give no consideration to other PAM plug-ins and prematurely terminate the pipeline disabling your keyring's PAM module.

Thus your keyring never got your password when you log-in so it must ask you again.

You may want to check the /etc/pam.d/ files and manually fix  them. The error is probably in the common-* files. Look for the line that uses the rogue "sufficient" keyword in the second column. If you want to manually fix this, you can follow the instructions in `man pam.d`.

Comment: Adding "eval $(gnome-keyring-daemon --start); export SSH_AUTH_SOCK" to the ~/.xinitrc seems to have helped me but apparently it's not foolproof. See also:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GNOME/Keyring#xinitrc

Answer (score 2):

Normally keyring gets unlocked when you enter your password while logging in. Then gnome-keyring-daemon process starts and manages it.

The **gnome-keyring-daemon** process is a **user process** (not a system service), so when you log out you kill all your processes (including the gnome-keyring-daemon). When you log in you start a new gnome-keyring-daemon process which needs your password to open your keyring.

If you have "**autologin**" then this is normal. Keyring cannot be unlocked because you have not entered the password. That's it.

Comment: I don't enter my password to login. It skips the login screen and goes to my desktop.

Comment: and that is the root cause. See past paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Both of these links have a bugfix for this issue, 
it sets the unlock for login to xfce aswell:

[unlock gnome keyring on ArchLinux + Xfce](http://www.reddit.com/comments/sdnjm)/unlock_gnome_keyring_on_archlinux_xfce/

[GNOME keyring often fails to unlock in XFCE](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1022322)

There are several `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-*.desktop` files. A redditor had success adding `XFCE` to the "OnlyShowIn" entries in those files:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;XFCE;
```

Comment: You should include the actual fix in the answer, or at least a summary of that.

Answer (score -2):

I am not an experience Linux user, however I think I have figured out why this issue is presented.
When you upgrade to a newer version of (Mint) and you have more than one user, you need to log in all of the accounts at least once.
On the reminder on the far fight of the screen, you are notified if you want to install any updates.
When you first log in, the update link requires you to answer:
 if you want to just keep my computer safe,
 if you want to view the offered changes
 or you want to just update.
This process has to be answered by all of the users you have created, select the update icon and answer how to apply the updates.
**All should be okay...(at least it works for me)**

Comment: The OP is using XCFE, and doesn't mention using Mint.

Comment: You say, “you need to log in all of the accounts at least once.” The question says, “*whenever* I log back in, I always see the following” (emphasis added). Exactly what part of what you said is an answer to this question?